# I'll get lost tomorrow?

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence correct?

> I'll get lost tomorrow.

Mom asked if I have plans of exploring the city alone tomorrow. The city is really new to me and I don't mind if I lost myself somewhere along the way. So is it grammatically correct to just reply to Mom:

> Yes, I'll get lost tomorrow, Mom!

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: But not *I dont mind if I lost myself.*  Either *I wouldn't mind if I got lost* or *I don't mind if I get lost.*

Comment: Hi Drew. But Mom wasn't worrying if I'll get lost. She didnt even ask me What if You get lost honey? That's why I didnt use those replies.

Comment: Does the above sentence not sound good.to you, Drew? Thanks. Thanks too Neil.

Answer (score 1):

It's grammatically correct, but I wonder if that's what you're really asking. It sounds more like you want to know if the sentence means what you want it to mean.

Your sentence is confusing since it seems that you're replying to a different question than "Are you planning to explore the city alone?" by saying "Yes, I'll get lost".

To be clear, you should separate the "yes" from the rest to ensure that you're first answering the question, and then adding further remarks:

> Yes, but I won't mind if I get lost.
>
> Yes, though I might get lost.